# How to update array values in nodejs redis.hget() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, node-redis

I want to create 2 dimensional array of chat log in which first array represent userid and nested array represent user related chat log. But I am not finding way that how to insert in array "arrChatMembersLog" in subscriber.hget() function. When I fetch array value it always empty and otherwise if I tried to print array in function "callBackSubscriberHGETMessageTable()" where subscriber.hget() call it shows 2d array with all empty except the message on which loop is running. Can you provide any solution for that I should fill all chatlog in arrChatMembersLog array().

Method Information::

> get_old_data():

It's main method where execution starts. User chats with desired friend by click on his/her name. when clicks it shows chat window and send very time message. As message send it fetches all past conversations between them. it fetches all channels created in redis.

> callBackSubscriberHGetAll():

it fetches message all message changes and store all messages ids in one array. using that array I fetch messages from hash.

> callBackSubscriberHGETMessageTable():

It fetches all messages based on array creates by call callBackSubscriberHGetAll() functions. Here actual problem arises. I would like to store all message data in arrChatMembersLog array.  But due to asynchronous nature of nodejs I fail to save all array value in arrChatMembersLog.

> Desired format of array

First index indicates Userids and second will be chat log of that user.

```
arr[1][0] = {},
arr[1][1] = {},
arr[1][2] = {},

arr[2][0] = {},
arr[2][1] = {},
arr[2][2] = {},

arr[3][0] = {},
arr[3][1] = {},
arr[3][2] = {},
```

> server.js

```
/*
 * -------------------
 * Express
 *
 * -------------------
 */
var app = require('express')(),
        http = require("http"),
        url = require('url'),
        cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'), // the session is stored in a cookie, so we use this to parse it
        session = require('nodePhpSessions').SessionHandler,
        sessionHandler = new session(),
        morgan = require("morgan"),
        expressSession = require("express-session"),
        phpUnserialize = require("php-unserialize"),
        sessionStore = new expressSession.MemoryStore(),
        parseUrl = null, uId = null, uName = null, uEmail = null;

// Transaction logger
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// must use cookieParser before expressxSession
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    name: "Whizchat",
    secret: '47760ae7-9660-4d4c-b15d-b9986edccbf3ss',
    store: sessionStore,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
        path: "/",
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: null,
    }
}));

//app.set(app.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
app.set('host', "localhost");
//var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
//app.set('port', port);
app.set('port', "3000"); //process.env.PORT

/*
 * -------------------
 * Socket Connections
 * -------------------
 */
//var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    parseUrl = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    if ("string" === typeof (parseUrl.dataJSON)) {
       var _objUser = JSON.parse(parseUrl.dataJSON);
        uId = (_objUser.user_id === undefined || _objUser.user_id === "" || _objUser.user_id === null) ? null : _objUser.user_id;
        uName = (_objUser.username === undefined || _objUser.username === "" || _objUser.username === null) ? null : _objUser.username;
        uEmail = (_objUser.user_email === undefined || _objUser.user_email === "" || _objUser.user_email === null) ? null : _objUser.user_email;
    }    
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': "text/plain"});
    res.end(sessionHandler.run(parseUrl));
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("host"), function () {
    console.log("Server up and running...");
});

server.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Error occured :" + e);
});
//io.set('log level', 3);

/*
 * -------------------
 * Redis 
 * -------------------
 */
var redis = require("redis");
/*
 *  Sender
 */
var publisher = redis.createClient();
/*
 * Receiver
 */
var subscriber = redis.createClient();

/*
 * Message counter
 */
//var messageLen = llen messages;

/*
 * List of all channels (sorted set using Z<command>)
 * Sorted set name : channels
 */
var channel_Count = 0;
var channel_name = "channel";
var user_channel = 0
/*
 * Lists of all users (sorted set using Z<command)
 * Sorted set name : onlineusers
 */
var userlists = [], usersSocket = [];
var uids = [], socketids = [];
var get_old_communication_channel_name = "";
/*
 * All Users related channels set ( unordered/unsorted set using s<command>)
 * Unsorted set name : userschannel
 */
var usersChannels;
var msgChannel = "messageChannelSet";
var messageTable = "messageTable";
/*
 * Message set (sorted set)
 */
var message_Id = 1;
//global array 
var arr_msg_id = [];
var arr_sender_reciver_msg = [];

var employees = [];
var arr1 = [];
var arr11 = [];
/*
 * User set
 */
var channelSet;
var countMember, countChannel;
var arrChatMembersLog = [];
/*
 * Identified that user_reference_id based set (unordered) is generated or not
 */
/*foreach userSet on <user>
    var countMember = smembers <user>;
    if(countMember is empty set or nil){
        isNewChannelGenerate = true;
    }
endforeach
*/
/*
 * -------------------
 * Mysql
 * -------------------
 */
/*var mysql = require("mysql");
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "password",
 database: "whiz"
 });
 connection.connect();*/
/*
 * -------------------
 * functions
 * -------------------
 */
function subscribeMessage(_subscriber) {
  subscriber.subscribe(_subscriber);
  subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    console.log("redis connection message:" + message);
  });
}
function createNewChannel(){
        //return true;
}
function showArray(){  
  console.log("My data:");
  console.log(" =============================== ");
  console.log(arrChatMembersLog);
  console.log(" =============================== ");
}
function insertDataInArray(index, loopindex, replies2){
  arrChatMembersLog[index][loopindex] = JSON.stringify(replies2);
}
function callBackSubscriberHGETMessageTable(messagesIds, index){
  console.log("messages index of i "+ index + "::" + messagesIds.length);
  console.log("message data:"+messagesIds);  
  arrChatMembersLog[index] = new Array(parseInt(messagesIds.length));  
  for (var j in messagesIds) {    
    var _index = messagesIds[j];
    var loopindex = 0;    
    subscriber.HGET(messageTable, _index, function(err, replies2) {
      //console.log("array index :"+index+":data "+j+":Ids "+_index+":Loopindex "+loopindex+" === "+replies2);
      //arrChatMembersLog[index][loopindex] = JSON.stringify(replies2);
      insertDataInArray(index, loopindex, replies2);
      console.log(arrChatMembersLog);
      loopindex++;
    });
  }
}

function callBackSubscriberHGetAll(i){  
  subscriber.HGETALL("message_channel"+i, function(err, replies1) {
    var k=1;
    for (k in replies1) {
      arr_msg_id.push(JSON.parse(replies1[k]));
    }
    callBackSubscriberHGETMessageTable(arr_msg_id, i);
    arr_msg_id.splice(0,arr_msg_id.length);
  });
}
function get_old_data(){  
    /*
     * Grep total channels created in redis database of all users.
     */
    subscriber.SCARD(msgChannel, function(err, channel_Count) {                
        var i=1, j=1;
        console.log("channel count :"+channel_Count);
        for(i =1; i<=channel_Count; i++){            
          callBackSubscriberHGetAll(i);
        }
    });

}
function setMessageData(msg){
  console.log("message call");  
  arr_sender_reciver_msg.push(JSON.stringify(msg));
}
function pushToRedis(subscriber, data) {
  console.log("push to channel"+JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log(" call first push ..."+data.uId+"==="+data.reciver);
  var msg = data.msg;
  var channel_name;
  if(data.uId && data.reciver){
      subscriber.SINTER("user_"+data.uId, "user_"+data.reciver,  function(err, replies) {
        console.log("get_old_communication_channel_name  :"+get_old_communication_channel_name+"=="+replies);    
        if(get_old_communication_channel_name != replies) {
              arr_msg_id.splice(0,arr_msg_id.length);
              arr_sender_reciver_msg.splice(0,arr_sender_reciver_msg.length); 
        }
        get_old_communication_channel_name = replies;
        //one to one communication in message new create  channels replies == 0 then
        console.log("replies SCARD  :"+replies.length);
        if(replies.length == 0){
            var channel_Count_no;
            subscriber.SCARD(msgChannel, function(err, channel_Count) {
            console.log("channel_Count  :"+channel_Count);
            if(channel_Count == 0){
              channel_name = "channel1";
              subscriber.SADD("user_"+data.uId, "channel1");    
              subscriber.SADD("user_"+data.reciver, "channel1");
              subscriber.SADD("channelSet", "channel1");  
            }else{
              channel_Count_no = channel_Count + 1;
              channel_name = "channel"+channel_Count_no;
              subscriber.SADD("user_"+data.uId, "channel"+channel_Count_no);    
              subscriber.SADD("user_"+data.reciver, "channel"+channel_Count_no);
              subscriber.SADD("channelSet", "channel"+channel_Count_no); 
             // subscriber.SADD(msgChannel, "message_channel"+channel_Count_no); 
            }
          });
        }
        console.log(" call first push1 ...");    
        //one to one communication in message new create  channels replies == 1 then

        if(replies.length == 1){ 
          get_old_communication_channel_name = replies; 
          channel_name = replies;     
          console.log("ch_name :"+replies);
          console.log("data.msg  :"+msg);
          console.log("msgChannel  :"+msgChannel);
          console.log("arr_msg_id.length  :"+arr_msg_id.length);
          if(arr_msg_id.length < 1 ){
            console.log("arr_msg_id.length After  :"+arr_msg_id.length);
            subscriber.HGETALL("message_"+channel_name, function(err, replies1) {
              /*
               * HGETALL  redis command to get all redord and for lop to javascript insert in this arr_msg_id array.
               * After for loop to get all record in messageTable.
               */
              console.log("replies1  :"  +replies1.length);
              for (i in replies1) {
                arr_msg_id.push(JSON.parse(replies1[i]));
              }
              console.log(arr_msg_id.length);
              for (i in arr_msg_id) {
                var _index = arr_msg_id[i];                      
                subscriber.HGET(messageTable, _index, function(err, replies2) {    
                   arr_sender_reciver_msg.push(JSON.parse(replies2));                     
                  //setMessageData(replies2);                  
                });
              }
              console.log("isert arr_sender_reciver_msg cumplited...");
            });
          }
          console.log(" call first push2 ...");
          /*
          * First time Add new messageChannelSet in message_channel1,2,3...
          * Not insert message_channel1,2,3... duplicate
          */
        }

        subscriber.HLEN(messageTable, function(err, replies1) {
          subscriber.SADD(msgChannel, "message_"+channel_name);
          message_Id = replies1 + 1;
          subscriber.HSET(messageTable, message_Id, JSON.stringify(data), function(err, reply) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Reply : "+ reply);    
          });
          //subscriber.HSET(messageTable, message_Id, "sender:'"+data.uId+"', reciver:'"+data.reciver+"', meg:'"+data.msg+"', time:'"+data.date+"'");  
          /*
          * message_channel1,2,3....
          * that match message_channel in insert ID and massage_text.
          */
          subscriber.HSET("message_"+channel_name, "msg_"+message_Id, message_Id);
          //arr_sender_reciver_msg.push({uId : data.uId,from : data.from,msg : data.msg, reciver : data.reciver,})
        }); 
        console.log(" call first push3 ...");
        //pushTOmessage(subscriber, data);         
      });
  }
}
function getCurrentTime() {
  return Math.floor(new Date().valueOf() / 1000);
}
function accessSecureSessionInfo() {
  //console.log("type:" + typeof (parseUrl.dataJSON));
  if ("string" === typeof (parseUrl.dataJSON)) {
    console.log("step in 1");
    var _objUser = JSON.parse(parseUrl.dataJSON);
    //  console.log("usrname;" + _objUser.username);
    uId = (_objUser.user_id === undefined || _objUser.user_id === "" || _objUser.user_id === null) ? null : _objUser.user_id;
    uName = (_objUser.username === undefined || _objUser.username === "" || _objUser.username === null) ? null : _objUser.username;
    uEmail = (_objUser.user_email === undefined || _objUser.user_email === "" || _objUser.user_email === null) ? null : _objUser.user_email;
  }
}
/* 
 * -------------------
 * Redis Subscriber
 * -------------------
 */
if (uId && uName && uEmail) {
    subscriber.subscribe("whizchannel");
    subscribeMessage("whizchannel");
}
var basket = {};
var index =0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var _subscriber = redis.createClient();
  socket.on('connection', function (cma) {
    console.log('Server running on *:' + app.get('port'));      
  });
  console.log("index:"+index++);
  socket.on("join",function(data){
    console.log("before start:"+userlists.length);
    console.log("datauid:"+data.uid);
    if(data.uid !== null && data.uid !== undefined && data.uid !== "") {     
     //console.log("after start:"+userlists.length);
     //console.log("Join called for :"+data.uid);
     //console.log("socketid:"+socket.id);
     //console.log("datuid:"+data.uid);
      var _socketid = socket.id;
      var _uid = data.uid;
      var _findIndex = uids.indexOf(_uid)
      if(_findIndex === -1){
        uids.push(_uid);
        socketids.push(_socketid);        
      }else if(_findIndex !== -1){
        socketids[_findIndex] = _socketid;
      }
      io.sockets.sockets[_uid] = _socketid;
     //userlists[_uid]=_socketid;
     //console.log("user array");
     //console.log(userlists);
     //console.log("users length:"+users.length);
     //console.log("userssocket length:"+usersSocket.length);
    }
  });

  console.log("Userslists:"+userlists);

  socket.on("chat1", function (data) {   
    console.log("frist call chat 1......");
      var _data = {
      uId : data.sender_id,
      from: data.sender_name,
      msg: data.msg,
      reciver : data.reciver,
      //date: getCurrentTime()
    };
    get_old_data();    
   // pushToRedis(_subscriber, _data); 
  });
  socket.on("chat", function (data) {
    console.log("After call chat emited......");
    var dt = new Date();
    var hours = dt.getHours();
    var mid;
    if(hours >= 12){ mid='pm';}
    else{ mid='am';}
    var time = (dt.getHours() < 10?'0':'')+dt.getHours()+ ":" + (dt.getMinutes() < 10?'0':'')+dt.getMinutes() + ":" + (dt.getSeconds() < 10?'0':'')+dt.getSeconds()+" "+mid;
    var _data = {
      uId : data.sender_id,
      from: data.sender_name,
      msg: data.msg,
      reciver : data.reciver,
      //date: time
      //date: getCurrentTime()
    };
     //basket[data.replies] = socket.id;
    // io.sockets.socket(to).emit(data.msg);
    console.log("------------------------------------\n");
    console.log(employees);
    console.log("------------------------------------\n");
    console.log("call pushToredish function");
    arr_sender_reciver_msg.push({uId : data.sender_id,from : data.sender_name,msg : data.msg, reciver : data.reciver})
    // io.sockets.socket(_data.reciver).emit(_data.msg);
    console.log("users:"+userlists.length);
    //socket.emit("publishMessage", arr_sender_reciver_msg); 
    //console.log("user.sender_id"+users[data.sender_id]);
    var _sender_id = data.sender_id;    
    var _uIndex = uids.indexOf(data.reciver.toString());
    console.log(uids);    
    console.log(socketids);
    console.log("senderid:"+_sender_id);
    console.log("receiverid:"+data.reciver);    
    console.log("index:"+_uIndex);
    console.log("receiver:"+uids.indexOf(data.reciver.toString()));

    if(_uIndex !== -1){      
      console.log("call to publish ....");
      var _socketId = socketids[_uIndex];

    }
    socket.emit("Current_publishMessage", _data);
    //socket.broadcast.emit("Current_publishMessage", _data);
  });
  //    socket.onclose = function () {
  //        console.info('Socket is now closed.');
  //    }
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  });
});
```

Comment: It's too much code to see, please, try to simplify to the least.

Comment: @Jonatas : Thank you.. I updated my question with more brief explanation that where to start debug code and where is actual error occurs and what does my desire result? Still if you have any issue with question let me know I shall try to explain you more brief.

Comment: The problem is that you put your **whole** application at once. You could have a question to each issue. For example "How to insert this object/array ...", and so forth.